# WPF TreeView - If I use binding, the ToString() is never called and the text is blank. If I set the items programmatically, it works fine

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview

The Classes

```cs
    public class TreeDiagram : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string CategoryName
        {...}

        public ObservableCollection<ImageInfo> DiagramsTRV
        {...}

        public class ImageInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Category
        { ...}

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return DisplayName;
        }

        public string DisplayName
        {...}

        public ObservableCollection<TreeDiagram> TreeDiagrams {...}
```

```xml
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="Binding"/>
                <TreeView  x:Name="trvDiagrams" Width="300" Height="400" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeDiagrams}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="x:Type local:TreeDiagram" ItemsSource="{Binding DiagramsTRV, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <TextBlock Width="250" Text="{Binding CategoryName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBox Text="No Binding"/>
                <TreeView x:Name="trvNoBind" Width="300" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                </TreeView>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

If I use binding, the Category Name is displayed, the The TreeDiagram ToString() is never called and the dropdown items are blank.

If I load the tree programmatically with the same data - everything is fine.

But for a variety of reasons, I need to use binding.
I have tried an IValueConverter to take the collection of objects and return a collection of strings - no joy.
Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

[image: Binding VS No Binding]

Comment: "If I load the tree programmatically with the same data - everything is fine." - and *how* do you load the tree programmatically with the same data? btw, in screenshot in background there is text "BindingExpression path error" - you really should investigate that

Comment: Please always post code that compiles if something is not working as expected. This way we can review it properly to identify any errors. If you deliberately post incomplete and erroneous code, it is impossible to tell real errors from your sloppiness.

Answer (score 0):

Your template is incomplete. You  must define a template for the child nodes too. You must either set the `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsTemplate` property accordingly or define an implicit template e.g. in the `ResourceDictionary` of the `TreeView`.

You want to display a recursive or hierarchical data structure. Since your structure consists of different data types, you must define a template for each level.

Note that `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged` is the default value of `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` and is therefore not explicitly required.

```xml
<TreeView>
  <TreeView.Resources>

    <!-- 
         Because 'ImageInfo' has no children, 
         define a 'DataTemplate' (instaed of another 'HierarchicalDataTemplate').
         If this 'DataTemplate' wasn't implicit, you would have to explicitly assign it
         to the parent's 'HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate' property. 
    -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeDiagram}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />  <== Force the call to 'object.ToString' by binding to the object itself
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeDiagram}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding DiagramsTRV}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```